# spray-http redirect to other subdomain

Tags: scala, spray, http-redirect, akka-http, spray-routing

I need to redirect all traffic without a subdomain to the `www` subdomain (e.g, `foo.com`->`www.foo.com`).

The code below is working, but i know redirecting code can be brittle and might bring security flaws.

Is this a proper way of achieving the above, or is there perhaps another set of directives i should use?

```scala
host("^(?!www).+".r) { h =>
  unmatchedPath { p =>
    schemeName { s =>
      redirect(s"$s://www.$h$p", StatusCodes.MovedPermanently)
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: changed `StatusCodes.SeeOther` to `StatusCodes.MovedPermanently`

Answer (score 0):

MY first error was using the wrong status code (`StatusCodes.SeeOther` instead of  `StatusCodes.MovedPermanently`), the second was only using the path part of the url

The version below passing my set of tests (see further below):

```scala
host("^(?!www).+".r) { h =>
  unmatchedPath { p =>
    requestUri { s =>
      val r = s.withHost(s"www.$h")
      redirect(r, StatusCodes.MovedPermanently)
    }
  }
}
```

This passes the test below

```scala
"Redirect correctly" in {
    "request"                       | "redirect"                          |
    u("http://acme.com")            ! u("http://www.acme.com")            |
    u("http://foo.com")             ! u("http://www.foo.com")             |
    u("http://acme.com/search?a=1") ! u("http://www.acme.com/search?a=1") |
    u("http://acme.com/search#abc") ! u("http://www.acme.com/search#abc") |
    u("http://acme.com/service/")   ! u("http://www.acme.com/service/")   |
    u("https://acme.com")           ! u("https://www.acme.com")           |> { (a :java.net.URI, b :java.net.URI) => {
      Get(a.toString) ~> wholeRoute ~> check {
        status === MovedPermanently
        header("Location").get.value == b.toString
      }

    }
  }
}
```